# What is the meaning of the function definition in the attached image?

Tags: functions, vector-spaces, vectors

I was reading a research paper, where I came to see the following the function definition and set definition. So what is 2^(R^n) here and what is the set X. Can somebody please provide examples also. Any thoughts will be very much helpful for me. Thank you in advance. Here are the images: [function definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p3yCC.jpg) and [set definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZJiKH.jpg)

Comment: Usually $2^X$ denotes the power set of $X$, but it's not clear that is what is meant here.

Comment: $f$ is a function defined on set of $n$ real numbers.

Comment: It is defined in terms of two "usual" function: the unary function $h$ and the function $g$ with $n$ arguments. Let for simplicity $n=2$; then $f( \{ x,y \} )= g(h(x), h(y))$.

Comment: The following is the research paper link. https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.00593. These are defined on page 4 of the paper

Comment: @MatthewTowers I have added the link in the above comment

Comment: Type images in mathjax, please.

Comment: @zkutch please refer to my comment just above your comment

Comment: It is not about link, but about comfortableness of your question - I think more people would like to help you, reopen question etc. if that definitions will be in view.